# Trying to execute an AMD fie on my Ubuntu!

Tags: 64-bit

I am trying to execute this on ubuntu within an directory that has these files.

server_darwin_amd64  server_linux_amd64  server_windows_amd64.exe

When i make this command below

./server_darwin_amd64 --www=../../FEF-UdaciMeals-Backbone

I get this error.

bash: ./server_darwin_amd64: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

Should i download some program to solve this or?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you have three files:

- server_darwin_amd64
- server_linux_amd64
- server_windows_amd64.exe

One is for Darwin (OSX), one for Windows, and one for Linux. Why are you trying to execute the Darwin one on Linux? Did you try to execute `server_linux_amd64` instead?